# R loop to calculate an average value based on data from different data sets

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to calculate the average of values from 10 different files (at line 15 and  column 2 in each file).

The first code below is working but I will have to change the number of the line depending of my needs (for example not line 15 but line 12) and I would like to summarize the code so I can change only one number.

```
error_m<-(file_1[15,2] + file_2[15,2] + file_3[15,2] + file_4[15,2] + file_5[15,2] + file_6[15,2] + file_7[15,2] + file_8[15,2] + file_9[15,2] + file_10[15,2])/10
```

I tried the code below but it does not work. This error is Error in file_(q) : could not find function "file_"".

```
sum_e<-data.frame(0)
q=1
for(q in 1:10)
{
  sum_e<-rbind(sum_e,file_(q)[15,2])
}  
  sum_e2<-sum(sum_e)
  error_m<-sum_e/10
```

Comment: R doesn't work that way (no language does, as far as I recall). You can dynamically determine the variable to retrieve from using `get(paste0("file_",`))`. This isn't the best way to deal with your data, but solves your immediate question. In the long run, I suggest you load all files into a `list` (using something like `lof <- lapply(list.files(...), read.csv)` and then get your values with `mean(sapply(lof, function(a) a[15,2]))`.

Comment: That should be `get(paste0("file_",q))`, sorry I didn't catch it the first time (I hit "add comment" and fled ...)

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly and solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**: fix the immediate problem:

```r
sum_e<-data.frame(0)
q=1
for(q in 1:10)
{
  sum_e<-rbind(sum_e,get(paste0("file_",. q))[15,2])
}  
  sum_e2<-sum(sum_e)
  error_m<-sum_e/10
```

**Step 2**: don't have a different variable for each data, when they are all structured identically. To start this, you should read them into a list and then process them as a whole.

```r
allfiles <- list.files(path="...", pattern="*.txt", full.naames=TRUE)
list_of_frames <- lapply(allfiles, read.csv)
```

At this point, each element of the `list_of_frames` is exactly one of your files, so you should be able to see `list_of_frames[[1]]` as the same as (for example) `file_1`. From here, whenever you want to do "some thing" to all of them, just do it to the list, but inside an `lapply`, ala:

```r
val_15_2 <- lapply(list_of_frames, function(df) df[15,2])
avg_15_2 <- mean(unlist(val_15_2))
```

This is now a list which may or may not be immediately useful. If instead you *know* that they are all the same size/shape (same length, same class) and you want them to be simplified into a vector or matrix, then you can instead use `sapply`:

```r
val_15_2 <- sapply(list_of_frames, function(df) df[15,2])
# or even
avg_15_2 <- mean(sapply(list_of_frames, function(df) df[15,2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Paste0 function to try and do the same function above

sum_e<-data.frame(0)

q=1

for(q in 1:10)

{

sum_e<-rbind(sum_e,paste0('file_(',q,')')[15,2])

}

sum_e2<-sum(sum_e)

error_m<-sum_e/10

Comment: I tried your code ( using "paste0('file_',q)[15,2]" as the files names are 'file_1', 'file_2', ...) but I have this error: " Error in paste0("file_", q)[15, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions"

Comment: sum_e<-data.frame(0), since this would be empty for the first iteration, the Rbind will not work because it does not have the same number of columns &  same column names. try creating sum_e with two columns with has the same name as file_1 then try rbind.

Comment: I found what was wrong, I just had to write 'get(paste0("file_",q))[15,2]' instead of 'paste0("file_",q)[15,2]'. Now the problem is solved, thank you.

Comment: That is great,Good luck